# MySQL show average per day of randomly recorded integer

Tags: mysql, date, average

Have a table that records time stamp and integer reading (date_entered, reading) from an electric meter (kwh). Would like to graph daily usages... most readings are daily, some are multiple days apart - random times of the day. Want daily average of the difference of the previous entry returned for each day. *Note the averages aren't accurate.

```
Example Data:
date_entered    reading
2012-06-01 17:02    18522
2012-06-02 14:56    18641
2012-06-03 10:55    18677
2012-06-06 15:16    18702
2012-06-11 13:28    18803
2012-06-13 17:33    18850

Example Output:
Date              Daily Average
2012-06-01 12:00    
2012-06-02 12:00    19
2012-06-03 12:00    130
2012-06-04 12:00    43
2012-06-05 12:00    43
2012-06-06 12:00    43
2012-06-07 12:00    8
2012-06-08 12:00    8
2012-06-09 12:00    8
2012-06-10 12:00    8
2012-06-11 12:00    21
2012-06-12 12:00    21
2012-06-13 12:00    22
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to create a table of all dates and then join on that? If so, you could easily fill in the gaps such as the gap between 06-03 and 06-06, then create a function that distrubutes across zeroes from the bottom-up.

Comment: Yes, I could do that... just thought their may be a cleaner way I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the steps you took yourself to calculate the averages manually. Here is its explicit explanation:

You have a list of Readings which hold two pieces of information:

- Timestamp
- Kwh aggregate

And you want a list of Daily Consumptions with:

- Date
- Kwh consumption

You should iterate over the first list and populate the second list:

For each Reading (starting on the second day of your records):

- Get the latest item in Readings which has a previous date.
- Compare the dates and get the difference in days (must be >= 1)
- For each day from the day after the latest reading and up to the current reading date, create one entry in Daily Consumption (unless they are already created because you have two readings on the same date)
- Get the difference in consumptions.
- Divide difference in consumption by the difference in days to get the average.
- Assign that average to the Kwh consumptions of each of the Daily Consumptions from the day after the latest reading until the current reading date.

Voilà!

It should work even if you have more than one reading on the same date, as it would just overwrite the average when you get to the second reading of the same day (just make sure you create only one Daily Consumption item per day).

Comment: Thanks for the advice... This is probably what I will do.

Comment: You are welcome. This should be enough. I was fearing you wanted to take into account the time of day of readings, which would force you to divide the days in different timespans before and after readings, cross-multiply timespans and consumptions... and make it more complicated for a very little gain in accuracy.